# Get original array structure from RecursiveIteratorIterator instance

Tags: php, arrays, spl

**Set-up:**

```
$array = ['level_one' => [
        'level_two' => [
            'level_three' => [
                'key' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]];
```

I prepare it for a filtering process that requires going through each individual value:

```
$recurIter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
```

**Problem:**

After the filtering process is complete I want to transform the filtered $recurIter back into an array with its original structure. How do I do that?

**Tried so far:**

```
iterator_to_array($recurIter)
```

This returns the flattened initial array:

Array
(
    [key] => 1
)

I want the original structure
iterator_to_array returns the original array structure only when applied to an RecursiveArrayIterator instance

Thank you

Comment: Can you describe the "filtering process"?  It generally makes more sense to filter before flattening the iteration with `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, e.g. by wrapping the `RecursiveArrayIterator` in a `CallbackFilterIterator`.

Comment: It's a simple filtering process where I unset values that don't match. I am using the RecursiveIteratorIterator because I don't know how deep the structure is. I don't know of another method other than writing my own recursive iterator that will keep track of the structure

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

`iterator_to_array($recurIter, FALSE)`

edit:

If you're doing filtering you might be interested in this:

```
/**
 * Select part of a data structure.
 *
 * @param array|object $data
 *   The input data to search.
 * @param callable $callback
 *   The callback
 *   $value - the value of the iterator.
 *   $key - the key of the iterator.
 *   $iterator - the iterator can be used to compare against depth + other info.
 * @param int $flag
 *   Flags for RecursiveIteratorIterator -
 *   http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php#recursiveiteratoriterator.constants.
 * @param bool $preserve_keys
 *   If false the returned array of results will have its keys re-indexed
 *   If true the original keys are kept but duplicate keys can be overwritten.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Filtered array.
 */
function recursive_select($data, callable $callback, $flag = \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST, $preserve_keys = FALSE) {

  return iterator_to_array(new \CallbackFilterIterator(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveObjectIterator($data), $flag), $callback), $preserve_keys);
}
```

Usage:

```
$selection = recursive_select($array, function ($value, $key, $iterator) : bool {
  return $iterator->getDepth() == 2;
});
```

or

```
$selection = recursive_select($array, function ($value, $key, $iterator) : bool {
  return $key == 'level_two';
});
```

Whatever condition you want basically, don't try and do this over a large data set because of performance, if you need large scale data filtering use SQL if possible but benchmark first with tideways/xhprof

Second edit:
I didn't see you want the structure left as it is after the filter `array_walk_recursive()` might help you here

Comment: iterator_to_array($recurIter, FALSE) doesn't work, I get the flattened array structure indexed by ints

Answer (score 0):

I have the same needs  and I have not found a solution for this.

So I have build my own function maybe someone need it

```
        $array = ['level_one' => [
              'level_two' => [
                    'level_three' => [
                         'key' => 1
                    ]
              ]
         ]];                

        $new_array = array();

        function copy_recursive(&$new_array,$array){

            $current =& $new_array;
            foreach($array as $key => $val){
                //you can also change here the original key name if you want
                if (!isset($current[$key])) $current[$key] = array();
                if(is_array($val)){
                    copy_recursive($current[$key],$val);
                }else{
                    //you can check or manipulate here the original value if you need
                    $current[$key] = $val;
                }
            }                   
        }

        copy_recursive($new_array,$array);
```

That return `$new_array` with the same structure like the original `$array` but this is not a simple copy from one array to other.

You can apply your code for each `key` => `value` and save it in the `$new_array` with the same structure